# Session remains intact even after closing browser

Tags: php, session

The problem I am facing is my session remains intact if I close the browser without logging out, if I set to restore pages (option "Continue where I left off" in Chrome). I have seen some mainly concern Firefox ([link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777767/firefox-session-cookies/1083020#1083020), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777767/firefox-session-cookies), [link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678483/how-to-make-session-ends-after-closing-browser), but I am facing same in Chrome as well.

So basically here where I stand:

**Problem:** If user chose the option to restore previously open pages in browser, Session remain intact even if I close browser.

**Reason:** By design

**My PHP Settings:**

```
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_only_cookies = ON
```

**Solution I tried:** I tried below by ini_set [as per this recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11108852/1951418)

```
session.cache_expire = 0
session.use_only_cookies = OFF
```

**Solution:** Yet to find one.

Comment: Do you want that on specific check user remains on browser other wise on closing browser clear the old entries ?

Comment: sorry, I was disconnected from net for sometime ... anyway, I need to clear any and all sessions once the browser is closed ... irrespective of user and browser ...

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to. The garbage collector will clean up your sessions.

The php ini setting session.gc_maxlifetime determins how long a session can remain active.
the session is destroyed when the user closes the browser**.

try this code

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 0);
ini_set('session.cache_limiter', 0);
```

Comment: What I need, if anybody closes browser, the session will expire. But if anybody refresh the page, it will not be destroyed. Things happen exactly this way if I don't choose the option "Continue where I left off" in chrome settings. But if I chose that, it just holds the sessions (may be till 24 hrs).  Now your code calls that function in every onload, doesn't it mean it will destroy the session if I refresh the page (CTRL+R)?

Comment: Not clear what do you want ? short and in simple words

Comment: *Session will get destroyed if I close the whole browser .. ** Session will NOT destroy if I refresh page or close ONLY the current Tab.

Comment: it still holds session after I close browser ... I guess it is Chrome/Mozilla's default behavior ...

Comment: if you made some settings in chrome or firfox then it will work as you set.Not depends upon code

Comment: hmm, I guess .. I was trying to find something that override browser settings ...